# Iterating over an array of objects python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to iterated over the array of matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot retuned by pandas.DataFrame.hist to make each subhistogram logy. The following example code does not work

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=1000)
y = x *x  +  50*x*np.random.randn(1000)
z = x * y  +  50*y*np.random.randn(1000)

frame = DataFrame({'z' : z,'x' : x , 'y' : y})

Histograms = frame.hist(bins=50)
for axis in np.nditer(Histograms,"refs_ok"):
   axis.set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip')

plt.show()
```

Comment: "The following example code does not work" -> What does that mean? Do you get any errors? Or unexpected output (what output did you expect)?

Comment: "Does not work" always means "does not perform as I expected" but we do not know your expectation.  So please state what you expected and describe the observations you've got instead.

Comment: Sorry the exception I get is "ValueError: Iterator global flags must be a list or tuple of strings" for this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `flat` iter:

```
for axis in Histograms.flat:
   axis.set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forgot to plot something ?
look at matplotlib sample :

```
"""
Demo of the histogram (hist) function with a few features.

In addition to the basic histogram, this demo shows a few optional features:

    * Setting the number of data bins
    * The ``normed`` flag, which normalizes bin heights so that the integral of
      the histogram is 1. The resulting histogram is a probability density.
    * Setting the face color of the bars
    * Setting the opacity (alpha value).

"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# example data
mu = 100 # mean of distribution
sigma = 15 # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

num_bins = 50
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
```